# Active MQ, JNDI, Spring error

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic, jndi

I am a starter in JNDI and JMS technology.

**I have my JNDI file as:**

```
java.naming.factory.initial = org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory

# use the following property to configure the default connector
java.naming.provider.url = nio://localhost:61616

# use the following property to specify the JNDI name the connection factory
# should appear as.
#jms.connectionFactoryNames = ConnectionFactory, queueConnectionFactory, topicConnectionFactry
connectionFactoryName = queueConnectionFactory
#connectionfactory.amqConnectionFactory = nio://localhost:61616

# register some queues in JNDI using the form
# queue.[jndiName] = [physicalName]
queue.requestQueue = dq-dataloader.requestqueue


# register some topics in JNDI using the form
# topic.[jndiName] = [physicalName]
#topic.MyTopic = example.MyTopic
```

**My spring configuration file is:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- <context:component-scan base-package="com.qpid.sample" /> -->

    <bean id="jndiProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="location" value="classpath:dq_dataloader-amq.properties" />
    </bean>

    <!-- JNDI template -->
    <bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
        <property name="environment" ref="jndiProperties" />
    </bean>


    <!-- local ActiveMQ connection factory from JNDI context available via jndiTemplate -->
    <bean id="amqConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate" />
        <property name="jndiName" value="connectionFactoryName" />
    </bean>

    <!-- caching connection factory -->
    <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
        <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="amqConnectionFactory" />

        <!-- set the session cache size -->
        <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="10" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="taskRequestQueueBean" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate" />
        <property name="jndiName" value="requestQueue" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**Invoker class:**

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate;

public class JMSSender {

    private static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(JMSSender.class);
    JndiTemplate jndiTemplate;

    public void init() {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("dq-dataloader-amq-beans.xml");
        jndiTemplate = (JndiTemplate) context.getBean("jndiTemplate");
        logger.info(""+jndiTemplate.getEnvironment().getProperty("java.naming.provider.url"));

    }

    public static void main(String [] argv) {
        JMSSender sender = new JMSSender();
        sender.init();
    }
}
```

But when I am trying to initialize them **I am getting this error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'amqConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [dq-dataloader-amq-beans.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: connectionFactoryName
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:608)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.jpmorgan.cri.dqaf.amq.jms.JMSSender.init(JMSSender.java:15)
    at com.jpmorgan.cri.dqaf.amq.jms.JMSSender.main(JMSSender.java:24)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: connectionFactoryName
    at org.apache.activemq.jndi.ReadOnlyContext.lookup(ReadOnlyContext.java:235)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:154)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to find the `amqConnectionFactory` in the `JNDI` because you try to get the object with the wrong `JNDI` name. You probably want to get the `connectionFactoryName` property value from `dq_dataloader-amq.properties` instead of the key.

Use `${}` to get the value from the properties file.

```
<bean id="amqConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate" />
    <property name="jndiName" value="${connectionFactoryName}" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: ${connectionFactoryName}. Name not found again. Sorry but i am kinda weak in JNDI. But it looks like it is not reading the name properly.

Comment: Try with "queueConnectionFactory" instead of ${connectionFactoryName} to check if it work.

Comment: First: Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: queueConnectionFactory
 at org.apache.activemq.jndi.ReadOnlyContext.lookup(ReadOnlyContext.java:235)
   Second: Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: ${queueConnectionFactory}
 at org.apache.activemq.jndi.ReadOnlyContext.lookup(ReadOnlyContext.java:235)

Comment: Are you sure that there is an object name "queueConnectionFactory" in the JNDI?

Comment: i cant confirm that. That is the JNDI file given by activeMQ. You would know better.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you had a simple case issue about the connection factory name.

It should be an upper case Q like this:

```
connectionFactoryName = QueueConnectionFactory
```

instead of "queueConnectionFactory".

Answer (score 0):

in dq_dataloader-amq.properties

you should define param

`connectionFactoryName = queueConnectionFactory` as

```
connectionFactoryNames = queueConnectionFactory
```

then update as

```
<bean id="amqConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
      <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate" />
      <property name="jndiName" value="queueConnectionFactory" />
</bean>
```

code in ActiveMQInitialContextFactory

```
protected String[] getConnectionFactoryNames(Map environment) {   
   String factoryNames = (String) environment.get("connectionFactoryNames");   

   if (factoryNames != null) {   
      List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();   

      for (StringTokenizer enumeration = new StringTokenizer(factoryNames, ","); enumeration.hasMoreTokens();) {   
          list.add(enumeration.nextToken().trim());   
      }   

      int size = list.size();   

      if (size > 0) {   
           String[] answer = new String[size];   
           list.toArray(answer);   
           return answer;   
      }   
   }   

   return DEFAULT_CONNECTION_FACTORY_NAMES;   
}
```